# Spring batch Multithreading approach -Chaining reader or processor?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have requirement for job that needs to get report for total appointments created at all locations and appointment types for data range.
Below is sequence to achieve the same.

1. Read list of 50000 locations from excel
2. For each of above location call a Soap Service A to get list of appointments created at that location for a data range and appointment type. The request takes in appt type and location.
3. For each of above appointments call SOAP Service B to get order number.

I was thinking to create multiple steps for each appointment type and implement multithreading for each chunck size.
If I have 100 locations with chunk size of 10, have 10 threads execute step.
Each step will have reader that will read excel file and that I was thinking if I need to implement composite reader to call Service A to fetch appointments and pass it to processor which will call service B for each appointment returned in list by service A or is it better  to implement composite processor which will:

1. Call Service A to get list of appointments (Use Async Processor) for each location chunk returned from reader
2. Pass list to second processor
3. Iterate over each item of list and pass appointment to service B to get order number. (Use Async Processor)
4. Use async item writer to generate excel
5. Then after all steps are done,combine excels for each step into one excel

Is there a better design to handle scenario.

Comment: Are you getting appointments type from excel also?

Comment: @Rakesh: I need to figure that out, I was trying to research if we can parametrized the step and pass the appointment type via parameter

Comment: You basically have a one-to-many relation: 1 Location -> N Appointments where each appointment requires a call to service B. The chunk oriented processing is typically suitable for one-to-one relation. But if you really want to use this model, the approach you suggest seems reasonable to me. I don't know how well it will perform with all these async calls though.